# Errors upon uninstalling MacPorts on El Capitan

Tags: macports, osx-elcapitan

I have a mac which I purchased having Mavericks installed and now upgradedEl Capitan. I had installed MacPorts earlier and now I want to uninstall, but I am getting this error.

```
 > sudo port -fp uninstall installed

  Error: Current platform "darwin 15" does not match expected platform "darwin 13"

  Error: If you upgraded your OS, please follow the migration instructions: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration OS platform mismatch while executing"mportinit ui_options global_options global_variations"

  Error: /opt/local/bin/port: Failed to initialize MacPorts, OS platform mismatch
```

The uninstallation instruction on the migration page of macports also leads to the same error. It would be great if anyone can explain the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MacPorts Guide Chapter 2.4. Uninstall](https://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.uninstalling):

> To remove all remaining traces of MacPorts, run the following command in the Terminal. [...]
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf \
>     /opt/local \
>     /Applications/DarwinPorts \
>     /Applications/MacPorts \
>     /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.* \
>     /Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg \
>     /Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg \
>     /Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup \
>     /Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0 \
>     /Library/Tcl/macports1.0 \
>     ~/.macports
> ```

EDIT: Oh, to explain the error. Your previous MacPorts installation was for a previous version of OSX, corresponding to 'platform "darwin 13"', but you are now running a newer version of OSX corresponding to 'platform "darwin 15"'.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the first two steps of the Migration instructions at http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration, then proceed with the normal uninstallation:

> 1. **Install the latest version of Xcode and the Xcode command line tools**
>
>    After a major system change, update the development tools by ​installing the latest version of Xcode. Open the Xcode application once after installation and follow any prompts. Install the command line tools package as well.
>
>    **Reinstall MacPorts base**
>
>    After updating the development tools, install the base MacPorts system for your new platform, either from the appropriate installer or from source.
>
>    [...]